# Objective C Reassignment/Memory Management Crash

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

As a relative Objective-C beginner, I'm obviously still not grasping certain memory management rules.  I can't figure out how to make this not crash:

```
@interface MyClass { NSArray *playerArray4th; }

- (void) viewDidLoad { playerArray4th = [self getAudioPlayersForSoundFile:@"rimshot" ofType:@"aif"]; }

- (NSArray*) getAudioPlayersForSoundFile:(NSString*)soundFileName ofType:(NSString*)soundFileType {

    //code instantiating objects....

    NSArray *toRet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:toRetTickPlayer,toRetTickPlayerCopy,toRetTickPlayerCopy2,toRetTickPlayerCopy3, nil];
    return toRet;
}
```

Then later, in a different function:

```
NSArray *currentArray = playerArray4th;
[currentArray release];
currentArray = nil;
currentArray = [self getAudioPlayersForSoundFile:fileName ofType:ofType];
```

And it crashes when trying to access the array again:

```
- (void) playSound:(NSString*)soundType {

    AVAudioPlayer *currentPlayer;

    if ([soundType isEqualToString:@"4th"]) {
        if (playerArray4thCounter >= [playerArray4th count]) playerArray4thCounter = 0;
        NSLog(@"Playing from array: %@",playerArray4th);
        currentPlayer = [playerArray4th objectAtIndex:playerArray4thCounter];
        playerArray4thCounter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to learn about `properties` and about using getters and setters. Don't take shortcuts unless you know exactly what's going on.

So define the `playerArray4th` property in your header file:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *playerArray4th;
```

And then in your `.m` file create getter/setter:

```
@synthesize playerArray4th;
```

Then, *always* use `self.playerArray4th` for assigning and getting the variable. The prior objects will be released when needed.

So this will not leak:

```
self.playerArray4th = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"text",@"text",nil];
self.playerArray4th = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"new array",@"text",nil];
```

because the second assignment releases the first array.

Furthermore, read about using `autorelease`. In short, if you `alloc`, `copy` or `new`, you should either `release` or `autorelease`. There's a lot to read about this here on SO which I will not repeat here now.

Don't forget to put `self.playerArray4th = nil;` in your `dealloc` method.

Comment: Of course you can fiddle around with pointers, but I wouldn't recommend it if you are not absolutely confident about memory management rules. What actually goes wrong in your code/understanding, is that there is still only one object if you say `currentArray = playerArray4th`. Calling `release` on either pointer will release this one object. Assigning something to `currentArray` will still leave `playerArray4th` pointing somewhere random, leading to a crash later on. So, use properties.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should have been using properties -- I'd still like to figure it out without them, but for now (and my level of understanding), that works.  However, when I access elements in the array later, they don't seem to have changed.  So I set current array and it equals: `"
    "<AVAudioPlayer: 0x55430b0>",
    "<AVAudioPlayer: 0x55435c0>"` then access it again later, but I still get the previous value `
    "<AVAudioPlayer: 0x533b360>",
    "<AVAudioPlayer: 0x534c810>"`

Comment: First of all: Pointer values are normally not suitable to base any assumptions on, unless you really know what's going on. I don't see why you need these two variables in the first place, but it also seems you're not sharing the full code, so it's hard to tell.